# Grayscale C++ with OpenCV (appears some noise)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, grayscale

i have some problem about convert to grayscale using openCV in make the manual function.
And this is my code.

main.cpp

```
unsigned int height, width;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  IplImage* image_input = cvLoadImage("duck.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
  IplImage* image_output = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image_input),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);

  unsigned char *h_out = (unsigned char*)image_output->imageData;
  unsigned char *h_in =  (unsigned char*)image_input->imageData;

  width     = image_input->width;
  height    = image_input->height;

  h_grayscale(h_in, h_out);

  cvShowImage("Original", image_input);
  cvShowImage("CPU", image_output);
  cvReleaseImage(&image_input);
  cvReleaseImage(&image_output);
  waitKey(0);
}
```

in this my grayscale code.

```
void h_grayscale( unsigned char* h_in, unsigned char* h_out)
{
for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
       int index = (i*j)*3;
       double temp = 0.3*h_in[index]+0.6*h_in[index+1]+0.1*h_in[index+2];
       h_out[i*j] = (unsigned char)temp;
   }
}
```

but the results are not performing as it should, it appears some noise in it.
[image: appears some noise of grayscale image]

I still have not found where the code that makes the error. :(
thx before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the input and output indices incorrectly.
First point to remember while working with OpenCV images is that they are aligned, i.e. each row is padded at the end with some random values. So while calculating the linear index of a pixel in color and grayscale images, `widthStep` should be used instead of `width`.

The generic formula to calculate index of a pixel is:

```
i * widthStep/sizeof(type) + (channels * j)
```

Where `i` is the row number, and `j` is the column number.

Translating the above formula for the current case, the indices will be calculated as follows:

**Input:**

```
int index = i * colorWidthStep + (3 * j);
```

**Output:**

```
h_out[i * grayWidthStep + j] = (unsigned char)temp;
```

You may create 2 additional global variables `colorWidthStep` and `grayWidthStep` along with `width` and `height`. Initialize the variables as follows:

```
width     = image_input->width;
height    = image_input->height;
colorWidthStep = image_input->widthStep;
grayWidthStep = image_output->widthStep;
```

Comment: thanks, its works.
but i wanna ask about the function of witdhstep?
and why it should make two widthstep for input and output??

Im sorry, im still beginner about image processing >.<

Comment: Widthstep is the actual width of the image (by **actual**, I mean the one stored physically in the RAM) measured in **bytes**, not in **pixels**. If 1 pixel of grayscale image is 1 byte, then 1 pixel of an RGB color image will be 3 bytes. It means the widthStep of an RGB image will be **atleast** 3 times more than a grayscale image of same width. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx). **WidthStep** is also called **Stride**.

Comment: @bagusbekam... You may accept the answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: thankss..im sorry i forgot to accept the answer. hehehe.
I added a new problem to the above question. I hope you can help me again. thanks

Comment: @bagusbekam... Well I told you the widthStep is different for color and grayscale and you **have to** use 2 different variables for them. If you don't believe me, print the values and see for yourself!

Comment: oh yes you are right, when I trace the error was correct witdhstep different for RGB and grayscale. hehe..
thx very much. your advice is very helpful